# Как сохранить заряд батареи Android-устройства (программно)?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Есть устройство. Днем оно питается от сети, а ночью сеть выключают. Ночью девайсы ничего не должны делать. По хорошему, они должны быть выключены.Как оказалось, выключить устройство стандартным SDK нельзя (устройство не рутованное и не должно им быть).

Вопрос: Как можно сохранить заряд батареи максимально долго, так, что к утру планшет не был разряжен? Мб кто-то знает способ как выключить устройство программно, не прибегая к root?

На текущий момент, мое решение такое:

- проверяю в сервисе момент отключения питания и погашения экрана
- выключаю wi-fi, bluetooth и перевожу устройство в **PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK**

Есть ли еще какой-то способ, сохранить заряд? Ведь через 4 года батарея износится окончательно, и возможно, устройство не протянет всю ночь на убитом аккумуляторе, с работающим ЦП.

**P.S.** На счет **root**. Насколько я понял, выключить девайс можно только рутом или системным приложением. Чтобы сделать приложение системным, нужен снова бубен **root**(?). Устройство массовое, поэтому решение должено быть в самом apk, т.е. никаких переместить в system, ничего подобного.

Comment: Мне одному непонятна суть вопроса? Это точно вопрос по программированию?

Comment: перефразировал на всякий случай, раз Вам ничего не понятно

Comment: PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK тут точно не нужен. Он предназначен для того, что бы не позволить устройству перейти в спящий режим. Т.е результат будет противоположный желаемому.

Comment: @АлександрКарачёв спасибо! а есть какие-нибудь другие способы?